# Django:AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: html, django

While I want to get the clicked values from website and search the result from the database, I set up a function and create the class, when I run the server, I can read the button but while I cilck the button the mistake occured.I will show my code here.
Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/hsa-GFAP_0019/

Django Version: 4.2.1
Python Version: 3.9.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'search']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\my software\mydoc\python\pythonlist\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "G:\my software\mydoc\python\pythonlist\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "G:\my software\mydoc\python\pythonlist\0.django_total\circRNA\search\views.py", line 70, in click_search_result
    return render(self.request, 'search_result.html', {'value_clicked': value_clicked,

Exception Type: AttributeError at /search/hsa-GFAP_0019/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    path('download/', views.DownloadPage.as_view(), name='download'),
    path('contact/', views.Contact.as_view(), name='contact'),
    path('search/', views.Search.as_view(), name='search'),
    path(r'search/?', views.Search.search_by_symbol, name='search result'),
    path('search/<str:value_clicked>/', views.Search.click_search_result, name='click search result')
]
```

The urls used for click function is the last.
views.py

```
class Search(View):
    def get(self):
        return render(self.request, 'search_table.html')

    def search_by_symbol(self, click=None):
        if click is not None:
            symbol = click
        else:
            symbol = self.GET.get('symbol', '')
        if symbol:
            interaction1 = TestCircModels.objects.filter(symbol1__icontains=symbol)
            full_name_line = interaction1.first()
            full_name = full_name_line.symbol1
            interaction2 = TestCircModels.objects.filter(symbol2__icontains=symbol)
            interaction = list(chain(interaction1, interaction2))
        count = len(interaction)


        def basic_information(gene_symbol):

            db_line = GeneInfo.objects.get(main_id=gene_symbol)
            return db_line

        geneInfo = basic_information(full_name)
        # sequence = str(geneInfo.sequence)

        return render(self, 'search_table.html', {'interaction': interaction,
                                                  'count': count,
                                                  'symbol': symbol,
                                                  'full_name': full_name,
                                                  'geneinfo': geneInfo,
                                                  # 'sequence': sequence,
                                                  })

    def click_search_result(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """

        :return:
        """
        value_clicked = kwargs.get('value_clicked')

        return render(self.request, 'search_result.html', {'value_clicked': value_clicked,
                                                           })
```

htmls

```
click file
                    <td><b>Gene name:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'click search result' value_clicked=full_name %} " style="color: #0f0f0f" id="{{ full_name }}">{{ full_name }}</a></td>

redrict file
 <div>
        <p>hello world</p>
            <p>hello world!!!!</p>
        {{ value_clicked }}
    </div>
```

I tried to give the function a request parameter, like function(self, request, *args, **kwargs), but it doesn't work, and get the error missing 1 opreator. So I want to get the method to click the button and redirct to a new website and return some data from the database, thanks!

Comment: You use the class-based-views in a wrong way, by using `path(r'search/?', views.Search.search_by_symbol, name='search result'),`, it will not work with the logic of a class-based view, and the request will be assigned to `self`.

Comment: So what should I do to avoid this wrong way, the path(r'search/?', views.Search.search_by_symbol, name='search result') I use could get the return from the database, and return to the webpage, I need to click the button in the returned webpage and get the message, maybe I can write path(r'search/?', views.Search.as_view(), name='search result') ?